# Having trouble inserting in a max heap

Tags: python, list, function, data-structures, heap

I am creating a MaxHeap class and I have to do it using a list. I am having trouble inserting an element into the heap. I am not allowed to add anything to the constructor. What should I do?

```
class MaxHeap:  

def __init__(self):
    self.Heap=[]

def parent(self, pos): 
    return pos//2


def leftChild(self, pos): 
    return 2 * pos 


def rightChild(self, pos): 
    return (2 * pos) + 1

def insert(self,element):
    self.Heap[self.__len__] = x
        current = self.__len__ 
        while self.Heap[current] > self.Heap[self.parent(current)]: 
            self.Heap[current], self.Heap[self.parent(current)] = self.Heap[self.parent(current)], self.Heap[current] 
            current = self.parent(current)
```

Comment: The heap produced by the answer is completely valid and satisfies the max heap property.

Comment: Are you sure this will work? Is the root of your heap at `self.Heap[0]`, or `self.Heap[1]`? If the answer is `self.Heap[0]`, then you need to fix your `leftChild`, `rightChild`, and `parent` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this (UPDATE):**

```
def insert(self, element):
    self.Heap.append(element)
    child = len(self.Heap) - 1

    while child > 0:
        parent = self.parent(child)
        if self.Heap[parent] >= self.Heap[child]:
            return

        self.Heap[child], self.Heap[parent] = self.Heap[parent], self.Heap[child]
        child = parent
```